# Grouping and beaming 6/4 time signature

Tags: beaming

[image]

I am confused about how to group the 1st bar, I think the half note will remain untouched, the two eighth notes will be joined. The quarter note will also stay as it is and then all the remaining notes will be grouped into one, right?

---

#### QUESTION EDIT

I was also confused in 2nd and 3rd bar,

In the 2nd bar, would all the notes stay the same apart from the last two eighth notes which will be joined together, right?

In the 3rd bar, we will join the first 2 eighth notes, then leave the quarter note and join eight notes in a pair of 4 each, right?

Comment: Since it seems you're unclear on this point: It's impossible to beam an eighth note to a quarter note, since quarters don't have beams, and you can't beam a note to a non-consecutive note. Thus, in the second measure, the final two eighths are the only notes that can be beamed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bar 1

You are correct; however, it might be more visually clear to group the two beat-five eighth notes together and then beat the beat six eighth note and two sixteenth notes together.

[image: Alternate solution]

MuseScore, for example, beams this way by default.

#### Bar 2

It's enough just to beam the final two eighth notes.

#### Bar 3

One of the principles of notation is to preserve the half-measure. So, most of the time, 6/4 will be notated in two groups of three beats each. Thus the beaming should look like this

[image: Proper 6/4 beaming — beats 3 and 4–6 beamed separately]

rather than this

[image: Improper 6/4 beaming — beats 3 through 6 beamed together]

Less commonly, there are sometimes situations in which barring 6/4 time as three groups of two beats is desirable. In that case, you would have the below beaming of beats 3 and 4 together, and 5 and 6 together.

[image: 6/4 grouped as three groups of two beats]

Comment: Hello @Aaron made some changes to the question could you review them too ? Please and thank you

Comment: @Swaraj Just checking in to see if this post answered your question.\

Comment: I think the last example beaming would be representing 3/2 instead of 6/4, at least by basic grouping.

Comment: Yes, the last example, although not uncommon, isn't really 'grouping in 6/4'.   It's a temporary shift into 3/2.